# MAAS: new host's IP changes after commissioning, but config files keep original IP

Tags: juju, maas

So, I've got a region controller, and two cluster controllers.  (All separate machines.)  Cluster #1 -- the local cluster, on a 172.23.x.0/23 subnet -- works great.  The remote cluster, on 10.2.0.x/16, doesn't work so hot.

- Systems PXE boot, provision, and commission great.
- Juju sees the new system(s) just fine.
- At some point during the process -- as is standard for MAAS -- the IP address changes from the "temporary" IP used for new devices, to the "permanent" address.
- The trouble starts when I do a "juju add-unit nova-compute".  The config files that get created on the new compute node reflect the *original* IP address, not the one that the system is currently using.  E.g., "ifconfig" shows an IP of 10.2.0.20, but here's what a grep in /etc/ returns:

```
    rgrep "10\.[0123]\." * 2> /dev/null | grep -v ":#"
    neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini:local_ip = 10.2.1.1
    nova/nova.conf:my_ip = 10.2.1.1
    nova/nova.conf:vncserver_proxyclient_address = 10.2.1.1
```

I've deleted and re-created the network twice, to no avail (including using different ranges).  On the verge of deleting and re-creating the cluster controller, etc., but wanted to post here in case anyone had any ideas.  Oh -- last thing: this is 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1~trusty1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any pointers gratefully accepted...

UPDATE: deleted and re-created cluster controller; still the same deal.  Interestingly, if I attempt to deploy to an LXC, THOSE config files are fine (though LXC fails as a compute node, for reasons I assume are unrelated).  Also, if I hardcode the correct values into the two files, everything works great.